# Java OutputStream and InputStream initialization

Tags: java, sockets

I have the following code:

```
    private Socket mSenderSocket = null;

    private DataInputStream in = null;
    private DataOutputStream out = null;

    ...

        try 
        {
            mSenderSocket = new Socket(java.net.InetAddress.getByName(TCP_SERVER_IP), 12345);
            out = new DataOutputStream(mSenderSocket.getOutputStream());
            in = new DataInputStream(mSenderSocket.getInputStream());
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException ex) 
        {
           System.err.println("Don't know about host.");
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O");
        }
```

I am interested in the following scenario:

During the chat session if an I/O exception occurs then I have to do the following:

```
mSenderSocket = new Socket(java.net.InetAddress.getByName(TCP_SERVER_IP);
```

Now what happens with the `DataInputStream` and the `DataOutputStream`?

Should I initialize theese objects again or not?

Comment: I didn't get it, are you trying to assign something to an already initialized final variable?

Comment: obviously not! 
if mSenderSocket.getOutputStream() throws an exception what should i do with the out (DataOutputStream ) variable?

Comment: I don't get it as well, first of all, why are you trying to declare as final de Data Streams?

Comment: because i want to synchronize on it but it is another story...

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I didn't get the question!

Comment: if you add the final modifier to your declaration of your data streams you won't be able to create a new instance of them.

Comment: Sorry guys, my question was not corrent. I made some editments to it:)

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly in an error condition you want to throw away the entire object and start again, or don't even construct the object in the first place.

(You also probably want a `finally` on that to close the `Socket`. As it happens, calling `close` on either stream or on the `Socket` will completely close all three objects.)